# Background timer in Xamarin Forms [PCL]

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, cross-platform

Is this possible Background timer in Xamarin Forms?

I have three buttons Start/Pause/Stop and Timer Text for showing the timer in my app.

When the user clicks on start button i want to start the timer. After some time user will close the app but timer should run in the background until stop button clicks.

and I want to send lat log to the server every minute even if the app is closed

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void OnStartbuttonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save the Time, when the Timer starts
    }

    private void OnStopbuttonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime starttime = DateTime.Parse("String with the Time, when the Timer starts");
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;


        TimeSpan difference = endTime - starttime;

        // difference ist the time of the timer
    }
```

I hope this helps you